# placement new equivalent in C

Tags: c, memory-management

Does an equivelent to C++'s placement new exist in C? I mean, can an object be constructed at a specified location in C? Can `realloc()` be used for that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no such thing as "placement new" in C. On the other hand, you can declare a pointer and make it point to anything in memory:

```
char *pointer = 0x12345678;
```

The above pointer now points to whatever is as the address `0x12345678`.

This is often used in embedded systems, where certain devices are at certain places in memory.

Answer (score 11):

Placement new simply skips allocation and constructs an object in preallocated memory. Since C lacks constructors, there is no need for placement new. I suppose the equivalent would be a pointer typecast, because once you have a pointer, you can act as if an object exists.

Example of carving objects of differing type from a common memory pool:

```
char *pool = (char *) malloc( 1000 );
char *pen = pool;

foo *obj1 = (foo *) pen;
pen += sizeof (foo);

bar *obj2 = (bar *) pen;
pen += sizeof (bar);

/* etc */
```

Of course, in doing this, you take responsibility for passing the right pointer to `free`, and looking after alignment requirements — just like placement new in C++.

Comment: Nitpick: *"you can act as if an object exists."* C doesn't really have objects per se; it has values.

Comment: @cdhowie: The ISO C standard(s) use the term "object" all over the place.

Comment: @cdhowie: C99, §3.14/1: "**object**
region of data storage in the execution environment, the contents of which can represent values"

Comment: @cdhowie "object" not in the sense of an instance of a class, but just a "thing" in memory

Comment: Of course. But the question is asking about C++ objects, and the two are really different things. It seems somewhat confusing to use the term in an answer to mean something different than it meant in the original question. But if I'm the only one who thinks so then I will cede the point.

Comment: @cdhowie C++ uses "object" in exactly the same sense. §1.8/1 provides the definition: "An *object* is a region of storage." (Note that this definition works because in C and C++, you are not allowed to do pointer arithmetic that goes from one whole object, allocated according to whatever storage scheme, to another object.)

Comment: Can you edit the answer to give an example of how alignment can be a problem in such a scenario, ie. an example of looking after alignment requirements.

Answer (score 3):

Since C doesn't have anything like a constructor, you can simply take the address and cast it to a pointer to the type you want to use. Of course, you need to ensure proper alignment, or that can fail (but the same is true with placement new in C++).

Answer (score 1):

The typical way to achieve this in a portable manner in C, is this:

```
#define X (*(int*)0x12345678u) // where 0x12345678 is a specific address 

// you can now use the int 'X' as any other type of variable:

X = 5;

if (X == SOMETHING)
```

This assumes that the address 0x12345678 contains valid memory, where an int will fit,  that you have direct access to. Systems with virtual memory may not allow direct access.

In embedded systems, declarations like the above one are common for defining hardware registers.